# How can I fill a shape with an image?

Tags: css

I am trying to make a diamond shape in which to place a profile picture. But I cannot find out how to make the image stretch so that it fills the shape.
This is my code:

```css
#diamond {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  /* Rotate */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  /* Rotate Origin */
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  margin: 5% auto;
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.profilepic {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<main>

  <head>
    <title>Your Profile</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet_userpage.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="diamond">
      <div><img class="profilepic" src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB17AjnXSMmBKNjSZTEq6ysKpXau/DIY-5D-Square-Diamond-Painting-Tabby-Kitten-and-Daisy-Flowers-Mosaic-Pattern-Rhinestones-Crystal-Handmade-Diamond.jpg" alt="Profile picture"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `clip-path` instead

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/400/400" />
  </div
```

As an alternative, apply a `scale` transform to the image at a ratio of 1.414

**Note** the value of 1.141 only works when dealing with a *square* element. Other values might be required for other shapes.

```css
#diamond {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  /* Rotate */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  /* Rotate Origin */
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  margin: 15% auto;
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.profilepic {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.414);
}
```

```html
<div id="diamond">
  <div><img class="profilepic" src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB17AjnXSMmBKNjSZTEq6ysKpXau/DIY-5D-Square-Diamond-Painting-Tabby-Kitten-and-Daisy-Flowers-Mosaic-Pattern-Rhinestones-Crystal-Handmade-Diamond.jpg" alt="Profile picture"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot
I didn't think about using the clip-path method